# Simplify This Trigonometric Identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac{\cos^2B-\sin^2B}{\sin^4B-\cos^4B}$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done besides posting this question?

Comment: Hint  difference of squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in details and justifications:

$$\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\sin^4x-\cos^4x}=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}=-1$$

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. :) I tried to give you an upvote but I am under 15 karma so it wouldn't allow me.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\sin^4(B)-\cos^4(B)=(\sin^2(B)+\cos^2(B))(\sin^2(B)-\cos^2(B))$$

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. I appreciate everyones help on this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{\cos^2B-\sin^2B}{\sin^4B-\cos^4B}=\frac{\cos^2B-\sin^2B}{(\sin^2B+\cos^2B)(\sin^2B-\cos^2B)}=?$$

And

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sin x + \sin(90-x)$$

Comment: Hey Yolo thanks for your help. :) I tried to give you an upvote but I am under 15 karma so it wouldn't allow me.

Comment: You can mark an answer coorrect by clicking the check mark @bill